# printing HL7 message in console

Tags: java, socket.io, hl7

I'm passing an object to constructor and then adding parameters of this object to HL7.
ORU_R01 is the type of HL7.
When i print HL7 to console, only the last OBX is printed. 
What is wrong with my code?
How can i write this HL7 message to socket?
Is there simpler way in java to handel HL7?

```
public class FlexSMessageHL7 {
private FileWriter writeHL7ToFile;
private PrismaflexSMessage sMessage;
private ORU_R01 message;
private int i = 0;
private OBX obx = null;

public FlexSMessageHL7(FlexSMessage sMessage) {
    this.sMessage = sMessage;
    this.message = new ORU_R01();
    createHL7SMessage();
}

public void createHL7SMessage() {

    // Populate the MSH Segment
    MSH msh = message.getMSH();
    try {
        msh.getFieldSeparator().setValue("|");
        msh.getEncodingCharacters().setValue("^~\\&");
        msh.getDateTimeOfMessage().setValue(sMessage.getTime().toString());
        msh.getSendingApplication().getNamespaceID().setValue(String.valueOf(sMessage.getMachID()));
    } catch (DataTypeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Populate the OBR Segment:time
    OBR obr = message.getPATIENT_RESULT().getORDER_OBSERVATION().getOBR();
    try {
        obr.getObservationDateTime().setValue(String.valueOf(sMessage.getTime()));
    } catch (DataTypeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Populate the PID Segment:PatientId
    PID pid = message.getPATIENT_RESULT().getPATIENT().getPID();
    try {
        pid.getPatientID().getIDNumber().setValue(sMessage.getPatID());
    } catch (HL7Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Populate the OBX Segment:Param_Code, time, Measure_Value
    while (i < sMessage.getMsgInfo()) {
        for (PrismaflexSRecord sRecord : sMessage.getsRecordCollection()) {
            try {
                obx = message.getPATIENT_RESULT().getORDER_OBSERVATION().getOBSERVATION(i).getOBX();
                obx.getSetIDOBX().setValue(String.valueOf(i));
                obx.getObservationIdentifier().getIdentifier().setValue(sRecord.getParamCode());
                obx.getDateTimeOfTheObservation().setValue(String.valueOf(sRecord.getTimeStamp()));
                obx.getObservationIdentifier().getNameOfCodingSystem().setValue(String.valueOf(sRecord.getMeasureValue()));
                i++;
            } catch (HL7Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    try {
        writeHL7ToFile = new FileWriter(File.createTempFile("prismaflexOutputFrom3001HL7", "txt", new File
                ("c:\\tmp\\prismaflex")));
        writeHL7ToFile.write(message.getMSH().toString());
        writeHL7ToFile.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Now, Encode the message and look at the output
    try {

        Parser parser = new PipeParser();
        String encodedMessage = parser.encode(message);
        System.out.println("Printing HL7 Encoded Message:");
        System.out.println(encodedMessage);
    } catch (HL7Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Replace the \r with \n. What it is really doing is printing all the segments in the same console line, so you will see the last segment, but if the last segment is shorter than a previous segment, you will see fields from previous segments at the end. Try writing the message to a file, you will see all the segments there.

Answer (score 2):

As Nicholas Orlowski pointed out, the problem is in the line ending characters, which according to the HL7 standard are CR characters which make a Windows command prompt only reset the cursor to the beggining of the line and overwrite it with next line's content. Therefore for console output You need to replace the line-endings with something else.

For a recent HL7 app using HAPI, which You also seem to be using, I made a little helper method to achieve this function:

```
private static String replaceNewlines(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\r", "\n");
}
```

The function can be used on all platforms, as it replaces the CR characters with the OS-specific newline character(s).

Then I can use it to output to console as follows:

```
LOGGER.trace("Generated message contents:\n" + replaceNewlines(outMessage.encode()));
```

In this case I am using log4j for logging to console, not simple console printout, but the problem was the same for me.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the HAPI? It is written for java, it's counter part nHAPI is written for .net as well.  Details here:

http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in my python HL7py library. Many times the console doesn't like printing  characters. I had to write a helper that changed CR to LF (line feed) to display the lines correctly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It won't display in the console but it will when you write to the file. Try looking at the variable in debug mode and writing it to a file.